# Error when Publish website "The type 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced"

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, publish

I have a solution with 11 projects and one website.
solution is successfully building. But when i publish website it gives me following error in a **.cs** file resides in **App_Code** folder.

```
Error   60  The type 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.   c:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\website--659085633\obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\App_Code\Generate_Response.cs
```

1) when i click on error file is opened from a temp location. 
2) Everything looks good in file in the solution. (as solution is building successfully)
3) Following code is already added in **system.web** section of web.config

```
<compilation batch="false" debug="true" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="50"        targetFramework="4.0">
       <assemblies>
          <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,              PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
       </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

**What I have tried:**
1) Restart VS. 
2) Removed and re-add System.Data.Linq assembly.
3) Deleted all temp files. (**website--659085633** folder in temp)

Can please someone help me with it.

Comment: is the `System.Data.Linq.dll` there in your debug/release folder (which ever configuration you are using to build the application)

Comment: Its not there in any folder. but when I add reference to "System.Data.Linq" from Assemblies tab. Prompt says its already exists.